# Linux application decode mmc ext csd

Tags: c, kernel, linux-device-driver

Currently from a user space application with su access, I am parsing ext_csd from debugfs filesystem, converting the string into raw byte data and passing it into a decode ext_csd function to fill in the structure that I wrote myself.

I am wondering if there is any more efficient way to do this, or less error prone? For example there is a 
**mmc_read_ext_csd()** and **mmc_decode_ext_csd()** in the kernel path drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c

Is there any way to use this driver function from user application? Or ioctl command? I can't seem to find any API documentation for ioctl commands for mmcblk0, only in the kernel source kode /block/ioctl.c

Is there also a way to see if the emmc is a high capacity card from user app?

Answer (score 2):

mmc-utils can issue ext_csd read through ioctl and output parsed text. 
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/cjb/mmc-utils.git/

There are others like these that can parse hex strings obtained from debugfs. It is hard to say if it is any more reliable than your own code. 
https://github.com/haoxingz/emmc5_register_reader

I am not sure about high capacity detection.